# How can I use both Steam Workshop and Skyrim Nexus mods?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I use mainly Skyrim Nexus mods, but I have a few mods on Steam Workshop. The ones on Steam Workshop don't activate, mainly because I launch my Skyrim through SKSE. How can I get them to work?

Answer (score 5):

You have to launch the game normally to make Workshop mods activate, but after that you can close and use skse_loader.exe again. Just make a backup of you mods' load order, since the default launcher sometimes "helpfully" rearranges them semi-randomly.

(This is why I avoid Workshop mods. Poor integration with community tools drives me up the wall and makes my mod set fragile.)

Comment: I always go default launcher > BOSS > Nexus Mod Manager > SKSE

Comment: @shanodin Yeah, BOSS is the way to go for load order management. But if you don't already have it set up it's an extra layer of pain/learning when you just want to use the so-called "easy" one-click Workshop mods.

Comment: @shanodin As long as you're aware of any newly released mods you have and remember to arrange those manually, BOSS is great.

Comment: @3ventic BOSS has a way of registering unknown mods and describing their load order position, so you don't even have to do that once you figure it out.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Forgetting to do that caused me a lot of trouble and CTDs just a day ago... It has a way but it's not bullet proof!